# Why does global object constructor print only the first 2 chars in Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I created a class called Fred here is the .h and .cpp files :

Fred.h

```
#ifndef Fred_h
#define Fred_h
#include "Arduino.h"
class Fred
  {
   public:
     Fred();
  };
#endif
```

Fred.cpp

```
#include "Fred.h"
Fred::Fred()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello Arduino!");
}
```

and in the sketch I just initialized the class object globally :

```
#include <Fred.h>
Fred a;
void setup()
{}
void loop()
{}
```

it should print Hello Arduino! in the serial terminal but it only prints the first two bytes "He", which is very weired!I have read about SIOF(Static Initialization Order Fiasco) it may be the problem but if so, why it prints 2 bytes instead of not printing at all.If I declared the object in the setup function it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `Serial` from a constructor of a static object because there's no guarantee that `Serial` will be set up. You don't want to do any "real work" until you enter `main`.

There's probably only two characters of hardware buffering in the arduino's serial port implementation. Once the first two are sent, the rest just get thrown away because the necessary logic to queue them and arrange interrupt service probably hasn't been set up yet.

So the first character begins getting sent out immediately. The second character sits in a hardware buffer waiting for the first character to finish. The remaining characters should be delivered to an interrupt handler (so that each time the buffer is empty because the previous character has been completely sent, a new character can start being sent out), but apparently that isn't set up yet.

Comment: yeah!So you're saying that I can't call any serial commands from constructor??

Comment: @Mustafa Not from a constructor that might run before the `Serial` object is constructed, no. Note that even doing it in a function other than a constructor isn't safe if some other object's constructor might call that function. You can resolve this by not doing "complicated" things before `main`, in particular, not constructing "complicated" objects whose constructors are non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In first lieu, trying to call methods of a singleton in the constructor of another singleton is wrong due to SIOF. Calling methods of an object while this object is probably not yet constructed is bad and can lead to weird behaviors. So, if the issue disappeared by avoiding SIOF on Serial and Fred, you do not need to question why it prints 2 bytes.

Edit:
How to avoid SIOF? there are plenty way to do so. But if you want to keep a singleton for Fred, you should use COFU (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Construct_On_First_Use)

Comment: how can I avoid SIOF in my case?

Comment: I have no control over HardwareSerial library in  arduino cores

Comment: Sure, that is why you *MUST NOT* call methods of a singleton you cannot control in the constructor of another singleton. You must do so through some functions like *setup* and *shutdown* that you may call in *main*. Only you know what you need.

Comment: So, Is there anyway i can send seria data inside a constructor of a class??

Comment: No, you cannot **because** you have no control upon Serial to apply COFU (that is, using `Serial().method()` instead of `Serial.method()`. 
Unless your constructor is not called as a singleton and is instantiated while running in *main*, which would be then okay.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid SIOF, you can do something like that:

I created a class called Fred here is the .h and .cpp files :

Fred.h

```
#ifndef Fred_h
#define Fred_h
#include "Arduino.h"
class Fred
  {
   public:
     Fred();
     void printMessage();
  };
#endif
```

Fred.cpp

```
#include "Fred.h"
Fred::Fred()
{
    // nothing to do here
}

void Fred::printMessage()
{
  Serial.println("Hello Arduino!");
}
```

and in the sketch:

```
#include <Fred.h>
Fred a;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
    a.printMessage();
}
```

Hope this helps.